# mySQL function to change 1 to "Yes" for multiple columns

Tags: php

I have this code which works great

```
  function GetMentalNewsletter($Carers_MentalHealth_NLtr){
    if ($Carers_MentalHealth_NLtr == '1'){
    return "Yes";
   } else if ($Carers_MentalHealth_NLtr == '0'){
    return "No";
  }
 }
```

I have another 5 columns that all have either 1 or 0 in the fields.  What I would like to do is a shortcut to assign every 1 or 0 in the specified columns to either Yes or No.

Is that possible?!  If not I will just have to copy the above function multiple times!

Thanks!

Comment: is this MySQL? I've never seen any kind of MySQL code that looks like that... and it looks an awful lot more like PHP to me than the type of functions (UDFs, stored procedures) you'd be seeing in MySQL. If this is not MySQL code, you should probably change the tag accordingly :-)

Comment: If you want change column value you should change type of column from int to varchar and save there string (not integer as you do now). Give more examples what you want.

Comment: Yeah sorry it is PHP.  I am not a coder and have been dumped in a project which I am trying to fix!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need one function:

```
function GetDescriptionFromBoolean($bool) {
    // MySQL considers a value of zero as false and a nonzero value as true
    // see MySQL Manual, Numerical Type Overview 
    return ($bool == 0)  ? 'No' : 'Yes';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that snippet is php. If so, you could use a ternary operator:

```
function GetMentalNewsletter($Carers_MentalHealth_NLtr){
    return ($Carers_MentalHealth_NLtr == '1') ? "Yes" : "No";
}
```

This does assume that you want any value other than 1 to return a No.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return it from mysql query then you can do following

```
SELECT CASE column_name WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes'
ELSE 'No' END
FROM TABLE
```